# Partitioning an uncountable space into an uncountable number of sequences

Tags: general-topology

Say we have a space $X$ such that every infinite subset has an accumulation point. Now we take an uncountable subset $H\subseteq X$.

1. Can we partition $H$ into an uncountable number of disjoint sequences?
2. Can we claim that this accumulation point $x$ is the limit point of a subsequence of a sequence we can define in $H$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question isn’t clear. (1) You can certainly partition $H$ into an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint, countably infinite sets, and each of those sets will have an accumulation point somewhere in the space, but I suspect that you mean something more than this. (2) What accumulation point $x$? You’ve not specified one.

Comment: The sequence here is a usual countable sequence $\langle x_{n}\rangle$. Sorry for the typos the touchscreen is a nightmare.

Comment: Any countably infinite set can be enumerated (in $\mathfrak{c}$ different ways!) as a sequence, so that doesn’t really answer my first question, and I’ve truly still no idea at all what the $x$ is in (2).

Comment: Brian, $x$ is any accumulation point in $H$. And is the reasoning behind your answer to 1. based on the fact that we can bijectively map the set of sequences to a subset of $H$?

Comment: My original comment on (1) is simply the fact (assuming the axiom of choice) that any infinite set $A$ can be partitioned into $|A|$ pairwise disjoint, countably infinite sets, simply because $|A\times\Bbb N|=|A|$. As for (2), there need not be any convergent sequences in a space $X$ in which every infinite subset has an accumulation point.

Answer (score 0):

To get this off the Unanswered list, I’m incorporating the comments into an answer and expanding them a bit.

1. Let $H$ be any uncountable set; then there is a bijection $\varphi:H\times\Bbb N\to H$. For each $x\in H$ let $\sigma_x:\Bbb N\to H:n\mapsto\varphi(x,n)$, and let $A_x=\operatorname{ran}\sigma_x=\sigma_x[\Bbb N]$. Then $\{A_x:x\in H\}$ is a partition of $H$ into uncountably many (in fact $|H|$ many) countably infinite sets, each of which is the range of a sequence of distinct points of $H$. This is not in any way topological: it’s a purely set-theoretic result. (It does use the axiom of choice to ensure that $|H\times\Bbb N|=|H|$, but one normally takes the axiom of choice for granted when doing topology.)
2. Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Certainly every infinite subset of $X$ has an accumulation point in $X$. However, $X$ need not have any convergent sequences at all. For example, the space $\beta\Bbb N$, the [*Čech-Stone compactification*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#The_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_natural_numbers) of $\Bbb N$, is a compact Hausdorff space with no convergent sequences. If $p\in\beta\Bbb N$, and $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is any sequence in $\beta\Bbb N$, there is an open nbhd $U$ of $p$ such that $\sigma$ is **not** eventually in $U$; i.e., for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a $k_n\ge n$ such that $x_{k_n}\notin U$. Thus, $\sigma$ does not converge to $p$.

If $X$ is first countable, and $p$ is an accumulation point of some set $H$, then we can conclude that $p$ is the limit of a sequence in $H$. Let $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be an open nbhd base at $p$. Replacing $B_n$ by $\bigcap_{k\le n}B_k$ if necessary, we may assume that $B_n\supseteq B_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Since $p$ is an accumulation point of $H$, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we may choose a point $x_n\in B_n\cap H$, and it’s now easy to verify that the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $p$.

Comment: Brian, doesn't every infinite compact space $X$ have to have an accumulation point? Proof: let us suppose every $x\in X$ has at least one set in which there are only finite other points of $X$. Then we select those very sets to cover $X$. This cover cannot have a finite subcover. My question is _does a space $X$ have to be both compact and Hausdorff for every infinite subset to have an accumulation point, or does being compact suffice?_

Comment: This is with reference to your statement "_Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Certainly every infinite subset of $X$ has an accumulation point in $X$_.

Comment: @Ayush: It’s quite true that I did not need Hausdorffness to say that every infinite subset of $X$ had an accumulation point. I threw it in because the question was about sequences, and sequences behave badly in non-Hausdorff spaces: if $X$ is not $T_2$, a sequence in $X$ can converge to more than one point.

Comment: I still have some reading to do before I fully understand some of the terms you have mentioned. Thanks for the answer Brian!

Comment: @Ayush: You’re welcome! (Don’t worry too much if the space $\beta\Bbb N$ seems pretty mysterious: it’s a very complicated object, and even the fact that it has no non-trivial convergent sequences is a bit non-trivial.)